# Rails: Search for substring without getting SQL Injected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sql-injection

I'm trying to implement auto complete for Rails. I have something like the following in my code -

```
Location.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:location]}%")
```

I'm afraid this would lead to SQL injection. Something like the following -

```
SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE (name LIKE '%green%') OR 1=1--%'
```

When `params[:location]` is something like this `green%') OR 1=1--`

Is there any way, I can avoid SQLi for substring based search in Rails?

Comment: Did you try it? Isn't this form supposed to prevent that very thing? I don't recall.

Answer (score 0):

Dave is right.  Try it and see what it outputs.  It wraps the whole thing up as part of the condition.  In my Courses model.

```
> x = "'') OR SELECT * FROM Users"
=> "'') OR SELECT * FROM Users"
> Course.where(["name like ?", "%#{x}%"])
  Course Load (38.7ms)  SELECT "courses".* FROM "courses" WHERE 
  (name like '%'''') OR SELECT * FROM Users%')
=> []
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Postgres, I would suggest using trigram support in Postgres to do this.

Throw this in a migration to get things set up:

`CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;`

then run your query like this:

`Location.select('*', "similarity(search_term, #{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(search_term)}) AS similarity").order('similarity DESC, search_term')`

or, just do what you're doing but wrap the param in `#{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(search_term)}`